# How to move to next tab on click of a button when using angularjs tab

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to move to the next tab by clicking on a button like "save and continue". I want to create a button to move to the next tab. Every tab contains some text boxes.

When the user fills the last textbox of tab 1 and clicks on the "save and continue" button, I want to display tab2. When the user reachs tab3 I want to hide the "save and continue" button.

How to solve this problem?

Html code is

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs col-xs-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 ">
    <li class="active"><a href="#info-tab" data-toggle="tab">Information <i class="tabs"></i></a></li>
    <li ><a href="#personalinfo-tab" data-toggle="tab">Personal Information <i class="tabs"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#address-tab" data-toggle="tab">Address <i class="tabs"></i></a></li>
</ul>

  <div class="margintop"></div>

        <form name="userForm"  class="signin form-horizontal col-xs-offset-2 col-md-offset-0" novalidate autocomplete="off">
<div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="info-tab">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <input type="text" required id="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName"  data-ng-model="credentials.firstName" placeholder="First Name">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" class="form-control" data-ng-model="credentials.lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="inputEmail">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <input type="email" class="form-control"name="email" class="form-control" data-ng-model="credentials.email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="lastName">User Name:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="username" class="form-control" data-ng-model="credentials.username" id="userName" placeholder="User Name">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="personalinfo-tab">
             <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="gender">Gender:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="credentials.gender" value="Male" />Male
            <input type="radio" ng-model="credentials.gender" value="Female" />Female
      </div>
    </div>

             <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="designation">Designation:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="designation" class="form-control" data-ng-model="credentials.designation" id="designation" placeholder="Enter Designation">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="address-tab">
        <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="mobile">Mobile No:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" class="form-control" data-ng-model="credentials.mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Enter Mobile No">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="address">Address:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control"name="address" class="form-control" data-ng-model="credentials.address" id="address" placeholder="Enter Address"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
         <div style="margin: 15px">
        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8 ">
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="adduser()" value="Create New Associate">
            </div>
        </div>
                 <div data-ng-show="error" class="text-center text-danger">
                    <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>

    </div>

            <button class="btn btn-small" ng-click="proceed()">save and continue</button>


    </form>


</div>
```

Javascript code

```
$scope.proceed = function() {



};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I got out from this problem by using "href" based on "id"s and script for moving to next tabs.. here is my html file.

my html file:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs col-xs-offset-2 col-md-offset-2">

    <li class="active"><a href="#info-tab" data-toggle="tab">Information <i class="fa"></i></a></li>
    <li ><a href="#personalinfo-tab" data-toggle="tab">Personal Information <i class="fa"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#address-tab" data-toggle="tab">Address <i class="fa"></i></a></li>
</ul>


  <div class="margintop"></div>
<!--  <form class="form-horizontal">-->
        <form id="accountForm" name="userForm" data-ng-submit="adduser()" class="signin form-horizontal col-xs-offset-2 col-md-offset-0" novalidate autocomplete="off">

<div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="info-tab">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <input type="text" required id="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName"  data-ng-model="credentials.firstName" placeholder="First Name">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" class="form-control" data-ng-model="credentials.lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="inputEmail">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <input type="email" class="form-control"name="email" class="form-control" data-ng-model="credentials.email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="lastName">User Name:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="username" class="form-control" data-ng-model="credentials.username" id="userName" placeholder="User Name">
      </div>
    </div>
              <div style="margin: 15px">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8 ">
               <a style="margin: 15px" href="#personalinfo-tab" class="btn btn-primary nexttab" data-toggle="tab" id="btn-next">Save and Continue</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="personalinfo-tab">
             <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="gender">Gender:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="credentials.gender" value="Male" />Male
            <input type="radio" ng-model="credentials.gender" value="Female" />Female
      </div>
    </div>

             <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="designation">Designation:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="designation" class="form-control" data-ng-model="credentials.designation" id="designation" placeholder="Enter Designation">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 15px">
     <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8 ">
               <a href="#address-tab" class="btn btn-primary nexttab" id="btn-next" data-toggle="tab">Save and Continue</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

</div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="address-tab">
        <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="mobile">Mobile No:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" class="form-control" data-ng-model="credentials.mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Enter Mobile No">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-3 col-md-3" for="address">Address:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="form-control"name="address" class="form-control" data-ng-model="credentials.address" id="address" placeholder="Enter Address"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

              <div style="margin: 15px">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8 ">
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create New Associate">
            </div>
        </div>
                 <div data-ng-show="error" class="text-center text-danger">
                    <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
            </div>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
```

my script file :: for moving to next tab by clicking on button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.nexttab').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it or not, but we do it by setting the active flag and having a list of the tabs. Something like the following.

```
        <tab active="tabs.tab1"></tab>
        <tab active="tabs.tab2"></tab>
        <tab active="tabs.tab3"></tab>

        $scope.tabs = {tab1:false,tab2:false,tab3:false};

        $scope.buttonClick = function(button) {  // button will be the name of the next tab to become active.
           $scope.tabs[button] = true;
        };
```